# How to style ListSubheader in Material-UI in the same way as in iOS UITableView?

Tags: ios, css, uitableview, material-ui

This is how my `ListSubheader` look now.

[image]

Nothing specific, it is only wrapped to the left.

But in iOS default header view in `UITableView` looks like this:

[image]

It has background color, different font different font color.

How can I set it? I am newby with `material-ui`. I need some kind of css formatting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using material-ui V4 (my answer relies on hooks), you can override ListSubheader styles this way:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import ListSubheader from '@material-ui/core/ListSubheader';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  listSubHeaderRoot: {
    backgroundColor: '#E5E5E5',
    color: '#252525'
    /* To change the font, use the fontFamily rule */
  }
}));

export default function PinnedSubheaderList() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <List subheader={<li />}>
      {[0, 1].map(sectionId => (
        <li key={`section-${sectionId}`}>
          <ul className={classes.ul}>
            <ListSubheader classes={{root:classes.listSubHeaderRoot}}>{`I'm sticky ${sectionId}`}</ListSubheader>
            {[0, 1].map(item => (
              <ListItem key={`item-${sectionId}-${item}`}>
                <ListItemText primary={`Item ${item}`} />
              </ListItem>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </li>
      ))}
    </List>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]

Comment: Do you know how to reduce height of gray view? In mobile it is usually not 44px but 22px height is has.

Comment: @János You can override lineHeight rule: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-44jho?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark